# Can i give a item with attributemodifiers, without removing the base ones?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I do:

```
give @p diamond_sword{AttributeModifiers:[{Slot:"mainhand", AttributeName:"generic.attack_speed", Name:"generic.attack_speed", Amount:-2.2, Operation:0, UUID:[I;11168,11168,-11168,-11168]}]}
```

but it does 1 damage, can it save the base ones(damage and attack speed), without adding more modifiers?
Or add a modifier with a new command

```
/data modify block -163 69 149 Items[].tag.AttributeModifiers[] merge value {Slot:"mainhand", AttributeName:"generic.attack_speed", Name:"generic.attack_speed",Amount:7,Operation:0,UUID:[I;11168,11168,-11168,-11168]}
```

but this removes the furst one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft 1.10: Add attribute to item without nerfing other attributes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288185/minecraft-1-10-add-attribute-to-item-without-nerfing-other-attributes)